# Choosing the right exterior door type for sound proofing from outside road noise

Tags: doors, sound-proofing

I am getting the door to my inlaw unit replaced.  Its not clear to me whether to get a solid core door, or a solid wood door, if my objective is to provide the best soundproofing inside the unit from the road noise outside.

Which door type is best for sound proofing the inside of the unit from the outdoor road noise?

Comment: You have to consider door, door frame, joint between frame and wall and the wall for this to be really effective.

Comment: But starting with what type of door?